# animation of uiimageView stops

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview

here is what I wanna do http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD3MTTPaK98
and here is my code:

```
-(void) onTimer {


UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];

 [imageViewArray addObject:imageView];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

[imageView release];

ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;
coteA=(240-ix);
coteB=(160-iy);
angleDeRotation=atan(coteB/coteA);
if(ix>250||0>iy>320){
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleDeRotation+3.14);
}
else{
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleDeRotation);
}
}



-(void)onTimer2{
for(int i=0; i< [imageViewArray count];i++){
    imageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
}
```

onTimer is called every 2 seconds
but it doesn't work, there is no error but when a "imageView" is created after 2 seconds it sop moving and go to the same direction of the new " imageView" that has been created. How can I solve this ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0):

You’re adding X and Y to all of your image views, but it’a always the last-computed value. Make an array of X and Y values and use the value that corresponds with your image view.

Where you define `imageViewArray`, also define `xArray` and `yArray` as `NSMutableArray`s. Then in `-onTimer`, when you set X and Y, do this:

```
[xArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:X]];
[yArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Y]];
```

Finally, in `-onTimer2`, do this:

```
-(void)onTimer2{
for(int i=0; i< [imageViewArray count];i++) {
    float localX = [(NSNumber *)[xArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    float localY = [(NSNumber *)[yArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

    imageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + localX, imageView.center.y + localY);
}
```

That will use the value of X and Y that you set in `-onTimer`.

Comment: Look at this line: `imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);`

Where do X and Y come from? The `-onTimer` method. But there’s only one X and one Y, so every time you set them, you overwrite the previous value.

Comment: it doesn't work, I don't know why. I use your code I initialize xArray and yArray in .h and view didLoad

Comment: You’re going to have to be more specific than “it doesn’t work.”

Comment: there is no  image of imageView on the screen no imageView displayed